# Computing Lebesgue density

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I want to better understand how to compute the Lebesgue density of points in the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Let me recall that the Lebesgue density of $z=(z_1,z_2)$ in some measurable set $E$ is defined as $$d(z;E)=\text{lim}_{r\to 0}\frac{B_r(z)\cap E}{B_r(z)}$$

Let $E=\big\{(x,y):|x|<R,|y|< R\big\}$ and $F=\big\{(x,y):x^2+y^2< R^2\big\}$ for some $R>0$

> What is the Lebesgue density of some point $z\in \mathbb{R^2}$ in these two sets?

If $z$ is in the interior of E, we can always find a $\delta$ such that $B_{\delta}(z)$ lies entirely inside $E$, thus the function $\frac{B_r(z)\cap E}{B_r(z)}$ is constant and equal to $1$ for all $r< \delta$ and hence $d(z;E)=1$ in this case. The same exact reasoning can be applied to $F$ to get the same answer.

If $z$ is not in the interior of $E$ and is not the closure of $E$, then there exists a $\delta$ such that $B_{\delta}(z)$ lies entirely outside of $E$, whence $\frac{B_r(z)\cap E}{B_r(z)}$ is constant and equal to $0$ for all $r< \delta$ and $d(z;E)=0$; same for $F$

It remains the case in which $z$ is in the boundary.

For the boundary of E:

Let $z$ be in the boundary of $E$; if $z=(R,y)$ or $z=(x,R)$, then intuitively the line of the rectangle should cut any ball centered in $z$ in two halfs, one inside $E$ and one outside. Thus $d(z;E)=1/2$ (same thing for $-R$). In the case where $z=(R,R)$ (or the other combinations of $R$,$-R$), then there should be exactly $1/4$ of any ball centered in $z$ lying inside of $E$, hence $d(z;E)=1/4$.

> Is it enough to say? How can I be more rigorous?

For the boundary of $F$:

> Intuitively it should be $1/2$ because in this case there aren't the points $(R,R)$. But how to prove it rigorously ?

Answer (score 1):

Since Lebesgue measure is rotation invariant, without loss of generality, $z=(0,s).$ Then,

$m(B_s(0,0)\bigcap B_r(0,s))=2 \displaystyle\int^{\sqrt {s^2-\left(s-\frac{r^2}{2s}\right)^2}}_{0}\left(\sqrt{s^2-x^2}+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}+1\right)dx=$

$2\cdot \left[\dfrac{2r^2s\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{4r^2s^2-r^4}}{2rs}\right)+2s^3\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{4r^2s^2-r^4}}{2s^2}\right)+\left(s-2\right)\sqrt{4r^2s^2-r^4}}{4s}\right]\Rightarrow $

$$\frac{m(B_s(0,0)\bigcap B_r(0,s))}{\pi r^2}\to \frac{\arcsin (1)}{\pi}+0+0=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: sorry, but who is $s$? You mean $R$ with my notation?

Comment: Yes, my s is your R.